# Re-parametrization of force fields in LAMMPS

Tags: density-functional-theory, molecular-dynamics, lammps, forcefields, molecular-mechanics

I am interested in trying to re-parametrize existing force fields in LAMMPS (let's say ReaxFF or MYP0) but I am not able to find any clear tutorial or information on how to do so. Do you know of good resources or documentation?

The idea would be to parametrize or correct a FF according to DFT or higher-level calculations... I have read that it is possible to be done with the AMS suit of programs but unfortunately, the FF is not available...

Comment: Do you want to refit the force field against standard results from DFT.

Comment: Hi, indeed that is exactly what I want but I am kind of restricted to use that software

Comment: What do you hope to do if you cannot fit to DFT?  This might be helpful to know for anyone to actually answer.

Comment: I have modified a bit the question... Otherwise I think I would have to manage how to convert one FF file and data into something valid for other programs that are easier to tune and modify

Comment: Emperical Force field have standard formulation, you need to find coefficient or constant through multi optimization technique.